# Make a ScrollView fit the whole activity

Tags: android, scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I can't find any answer to this question, I've an activity which layout contains (in this order) a `TextView`, an `ImageView` and a `ScrollView`. In this `ScrollView`, there is a `RelativeLayout` which contains several things. Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background= "#7a9965"
tools:context="pact.smartpen.AboutActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="À propos de"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <TextView
                android:text="foo foo foo foo foo foo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="bar bar bar bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that the ScrollView doesn't fit properly the screen.

Comment: do you want to set scroll for entire layout ?

Comment: Remove paddings from root layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase this from `<RelativeLayout>` :

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

That code is giving a whole padding to your activity.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background= "#7a9965"
tools:context="pact.smartpen.AboutActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="À propos de"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <TextView
                android:text="Cette application a été développée par 9 élèves de l'école Télécom ParisTech dans le cadre du projet PACT \n \n Arnaud Bonetti \n Oumayma Bounou \n Quentin Chabert \n Benoit Colas \n Fatimata Fall \n Anthony Hu \n Guillaume Grelet \n Louis Marty \n Nicolas Pontois \n \n \n Le code est disponible sur GitHub à l'adresse suivante :\n "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="https://github.com/PACT11/SmartPen.git \n \n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```